# Does continuity follow from linearity on all or only finite-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm currently reading an introduction book on topology. While solving one of its exercises I came across something odd.

The exercise is:

Let $E$ and $F$ be normed spaces, let $T:E \to F$ be linear, and suppose that $\dim E < \infty$. Show that $T$ is continuous. (Hint: For $x \in E$, define $|||x||| := \max\{ \|x\|, \|T(x)\| \}$; show that $||| \cdot |||$ is a norm on $E$, and use Proposition B.1.)

Proposition B.1 states that if $E$ is a finite-dimensional linear space and $\| \cdot \|$ and $||| \cdot |||$ are norms on $E$. Then there is a constant $C \ge 0$ such that

$\|x\| \le C |||x|||$ and $|||x||| \le C\|x\|$

It was pretty easy to proof it using the hint but I also found a proof that doesn't need $E$ to be finite-dimensional:

Since $T$ is linear we have

$\|T(x)\| = \|x\| \cdot \|T(1)\|$

Set $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{\|T(1)\|}$, then we get

$\|x-y\| < \delta\\ \Rightarrow \|T(1)\| \|x-y\| < \varepsilon\\ \Rightarrow \|T(x-y)\| < \varepsilon\\ \Rightarrow \|T(x) - T(y)\| < \varepsilon$

Thus $T$ is continuous even if $E$ is not a finite-dimensional space.

Now my question is whether the exercise assumes something that's actually not needed to proof that $T$ is continuous or if my proof somewhere secretly assumes $E$ to be finite-dimensional.

Thanks

Comment: What is $1$ in $T(1)$? On all infinite-dimensional normed spaces, there are discontinuous linear maps.

Comment: Oh you are right. I'm only allowed to take scalars out but I took a vector out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Basically, what is used eventually is that the closed unit ball is compact only in finite-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You might find it useful to look at a fairly simple infinite-dimensional counterexample. Let $P$ be the linear space of all polynomials with real coefficients. If $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n\in P$, define $\|p\|=\max\{|a_0|,\ldots,|a_n|\}$; it’s not hard to check that $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $P$.

Define $\varphi:P\to P$ as follows: for $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\in P$, let $\varphi(p)$ be the polynomial

$$\left(\varphi(p)\right)(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n2^ka_kx^n=a_0+2a_1x+4a_2x^2+\ldots+2^na_nx^n\;.$$

It’s easy to check that $\varphi$ is linear.

Now let $p_0(x)=1$, $p_1(x)=\frac12+\frac12x$, $p_2(x)=\frac14+\frac14x+\frac14x^2$, and in general

$$p_n(x)=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^nx^k\;;$$

clearly $\|p_n\|=\frac1{2^n}$, so $\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to the zero polynomial. If $\varphi$ were continuous, $\langle\varphi(p_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ would also converge to the zero polynomial, but clearly

$$\varphi\left(p_n(x)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2^k}{2^n}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{2^{n-k}}x^k=\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^{n-1}}x+\ldots+\frac12x^{n-1}+x^n\;,$$

so $\|\varphi(p_n)\|=1$, and the sequence $\langle\varphi(p_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ cannot converge to the zero polynomial. Thus, $\varphi$ is linear but not continuous.